How to make an overlay on left and right of horizontally oriented recyclerview?
I have a recycler view which shows sizes. The recycler view is oriented horizontally. On let and right of the recycler view I want to add white gradient shadow.
This is the code I use:
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
      android:id="@+id/sizeRecyclerView"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
      android:orientation="horizontal" />



You could try adding two views with gradient background above the Recyclerview.


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp">

    <!--  Replace this TextView with RecyclerView  -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="MMMMMMMMMMMMM"
        android:textSize="35sp" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient"
        android:focusable="false"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/gradient_backward"
        android:focusable="false"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>



drawable/gradient.xml


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:endColor="#00FFFFFF"
        android:startColor="#FFFFFFFF" />
</shape>



drawable/gradient_backward


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:angle="180"
        android:endColor="#00FFFFFF"
        android:startColor="#FFFFFFFF" />
</shape>



